# Sliding of an image using carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem with carousel,
   I have tried a lot, but I am not able to solve
    I have one carousel with 4 images.Here i want to like in 1st iteration:
    1-2-3-4
    2nd iteration: 4-5-6-7
    3rd iteration:7-8-9-10
   this will when we click on corousel.
    here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="CustomStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: false
    })


    $('.carousel .item').each(function(){
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
            next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25% ; }
.class-inner .active.right{left : 25%;}
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  25% ; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left:  -25% ; }
.carousel-control            { width:  4%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:-15px;background-image:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>




<div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style=" direction: ltr">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="1.jpg" href="sa.html" class="img-responsive">1</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="2.jpg" class="img-responsive">2</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="3.jpg" class="img-responsive">3</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="4.jpg" class="img-responsive">4</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="5.jpg" class="img-responsive">5</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="6.jpg" class="img-responsive">6</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="7.jpg" class="img-responsive">7</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="8.jpg" class="img-responsive">8</a></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use a different carousel:

http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-dynamic-number-slides

It's easy to use and responsive ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here you find exactly what you want.

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Please find below working demo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Slick Playground</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }

    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }

    .slick-slide img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
        color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <section class="regular slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
    </div>
  </section>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
      $(".regular").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thankx , but it is not working. Give me an alternative solution please..

Comment: yeah, i have checked

Comment: Here, i want in 1st iteration:1-2-3-4, 2nd iteration:4-5-6-7, 3rd iteration:7-8-9-10

Comment: change below values,
slidesToShow: 4,
slidesToScroll: 3